# Нахождение точки на прямой

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, любой-язык

[image: Картинка]

Имеется, например, канва. На ней есть 4 квадрата. Первый и последний образуют между собой линию. Любые другие квадраты надо сдвинуть к этой прямой так, чтобы их центры находились в точке на прямой. То есть сдвинуть их перпендикулярно вверх или вниз относительно этой точки (как показано на рисунке). Как можно определить эти самые точки на прямой, в которых должны оказаться квадраты?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67655/discussion-on-question-by-alladuh----).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Находим `a` и `b`:

```
y1 = a * x1 + b
y4 = a * x4 + b
```

Теперь, чтобы переместить 2 и 3 квадраты, координату `x` оставляем на месте, а координату `y` меняем:

```
y2 = a * x2 + b
```

где `x2`, `a`, `b` у нас известны.

```
List<Rectangle> listRectangles; //Уже содержит все квадраты
double x, y, a, b;
Rectangle minElement = listRectangles.First();
Rectangle maxElement = listRectangles.First();
foreach(Rectangle element in listRectangles)
{
   if(minElement.Center.X > element.Center.X) minElement = element;
   if(maxElement.Center.X < element.Center.X) maxElement = element;
}
a = (minElement.Center.Y - maxElement.Center.Y) / (minElement.Center.X - maxElement.Center.X);
b = minElement.Center.Y - a * minElement.Center.X;

foreach(Rectangle element in listRectangles)
{
    if(element.Center.Y == minElement.Center.Y) continue;
    if(element.Center.Y == maxElement.Center.Y) continue;
    element.Center.Y = a * element.Center.X + b;
}
```

Comment: Быть можете код для демо напишите? Ну типа сайт программистов :)